# prevent window from overlapping other visible windows

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I'm dealing with a panel that have several windows inside it.

Is there a way for the windows to not overlap each other when they are re-positioned by the user?

What class/es should I work on?

Here is a very discrete sample to work on. http://jsfiddle.net/jopantorilla/XFC6P/1/

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
var window1, window2;
var parentWindow = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
    title: 'Parent Window',
    layout: 'fit',
    width: 500,
    height: 450,
    items: [
    window1 = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
        title: 'Window 1',
        id: 'window1',
        width: 150,
        height: 150,
        x: 50,
        y: 100,
        constrain: true
    }),
    window2 = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
        title: 'Window 2',
        id: 'window2',
        width: 150,
        height: 150,
        x: 300,
        y: 100,
        constrain: true
    })]
}).show();

window1.show();
window2.show();
```

});

Comment: try implementing portal layout http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/portal/portal.html

Answer (score -1):

Use the `WindowManager` to control the behavior of the overlap.

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.WindowManager

Comment: Please include an explanation on how to use WindowManager to accomplish the task at hand.